# How many objects eligible for Garbage Collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, scjp, ocpjp

```
class A{
     A aob;
     public static void main(String args[]){
          A a=new A();
          A b=new A();
          A c=new A();
          a.aob=b;
          b.aob=a;
          c.aob=a.aob;
          A d=new A().aob=new A();  //tricky assignement
          c=b;                      //one object eligible GC
          c.aob=null;
          System.gc();
     }
}
```

There is two objectcs eligible for garbage collection but one is difficult to understand.

```
A d=new A().aob=new A();
```

**1)** This line I thing that it would make this

```
A d = new A().aob = new A();
          ^             ^
          O1            O2

      O1 --> O2 --> null
      ^
      |
d ----|
```

**2)** But what really is doing is this (so one eligible object) **WHY IS LIKE THIS?**

```
A d = new A().aob = new A();
          ^             ^
          O1            O2

      O1 --> O2 --> null
             ^
             |
d -----------|
```

because the assignements are associative right to left.

```
A d = ( new A().aob = new A() );
```

Could anyone explain it otherwise?
Thanks

Comment: Two points: First, your second diagram should have `O2 --> O1 --> null`. Second, the other object eligible for gc is the original instance of `A` assigned to `c` in `A c = new A();`. Presumably you knew this one, but it wasn't mentioned so I thought I'd mention it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It starts from right to left. First `new A()` is executed and a new object is created. Then it is assigned to the field `aob` of another new object `A`. Finally `d` is referencing the property `aob`. This means the second object `A` is eligible for garbage collection.

It is like:

```
A firstA = new A();
A secondA = new A();
secondA.aob = firstA;
A d = secondA.aob;
```

But the `secondA` object is created inline so there are no references to it and it is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: A d = new A().aob = new A();
---- will be the same as ---
A d = new A();
new A().aob = d;

Answer (score 0):

In this example what would you expect?

```
A a = new A();
A b = new A();
a.aob = b;
A d = a.aob;
```

would `d` be the instance `a` or the instance `b`?

Would you expect it to be different just because you are creating the objects inline?

in this example surely `d` must be object `b`, and so object `a` is not referenced and can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

```
A d = new A().aob = new A();
```

In Java, the assignment operator is right-associative, i.e. they are evaluated from right-to-left. But also, they are in the least precedence operators group.

So the second new operator (right of the second equality) is evaluated first and we get a new A object; let's say '**a**'. Now we have:

```
new A().aob = a;
```

The trick here is to recognize the operator precedence. Take a look at here: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~willb/cs302/spring-07/java-operator-precedence.pdf

The 'new' operator and the '.' method call operator have the same precedence but their associative quality are reversed: 'new' is right-associative and '.' is left-associative.

So the compiler first applies the new operator on the 'right operand' which is here 'A()' (before the next operand comes into place). Let's call the new object **b**; and we have:

```
A d = b.aob = a;
```

The compiler now needs to apply the '.' operator first (as '.' has higher precedence than '=' operator). Let's call the object referred by 'b.aob' as **c**:

```
A d = c = a;
```

Finally all that is left are the assignment operators and they are right-associative (evaluated from right-to-left). So, **a** is assigned to **c** (b.aob) first, and then **c** is assigned to **d**.